# Foursquare App Authentication Redirect not working when user logins with Facebook

Tags: php, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, foursquare

While my app try to authenticate an user with Foursquare using the 'code flow' as described in https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth when he or she is not already logged in on Foursquare, it prompts him or her to log in to continue. That's okey.

After that, when the user logs in with user/password, the flow continues as expected, but, if the user decides to login using his/her Facebook account, the app's authorization flow is broken directing the user to Foursquare home.

Is there a way of avoiding this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi marcomtz85, thanks for bringing up this issue. We'll investigate this on our end.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing up the issue - this should be fixed now, and your users will be able to log in with Facebook during the OAuth flow.